# Traversing the Line Plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, neural-network

I'm trying to demonstrate a cost function right now and wondering if there's a way to traverse the parabola by adding plot in the same subplot and figure.

```
def costfuntion(b, a):
    # b Value
    x = np.linspace(b*(-b), b*(b), 100)
    y = (x - a)**2
    return y
```

My Plot Attempt:

```
plt.plot(costfuntion(20,5))
plt.ylabel("Cost Value");

#b = 'some b value'
plt.plot(b, marker='o', color='b')
```

[What I'm trying to mimic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gvq9sUHPgrc)
(Around: 1:13)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `y` values depend on the `a` values you need to specify an `a` for the `y` lookup. Consider the following:

```
def costfunction(b, a):
    # b Value
    x = np.linspace(b*(-b), b*(b), 100)
    y = (x - a)**2
    return x, y
a = 5
c = costfunction(20, a)
plt.plot(c[0], c[1], linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
plt.ylabel("Cost Value");

b = 100
yb = (b - a)**2    # Find the corresponding y-value
plt.plot(b, yb, marker='o', color='b')
plt.show()
```

This will give you

[image: Cost function with tracer]

You might also note that I modified the `costfunction` definition to return the `x` values, otherwise matplotlib will just use whatever values it pleases.

Answer (score 1):

```
def costfuntion(b, a):
    # b Value
    x = np.linspace(b*(-b), b*(b), 100)
    y = (x - a)**2
    return x, y

x, y = costfuntion(20,5)
plt.plot(x, y)
for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
    plt.plot(x[i], y[i], marker='o', color='b')
```

Change the cost function to return both `x` and `y` of the function you are plotting and use this information to plot points on the function.